# Is the sentence correct "Programs are now can be run"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Is the sentence correct "Programs are now can be deleted" ?
The question is about verb "are", is it needed here? And if not, is it still acceptable to use it?

Comment: It would be very unusual to use the phrase ***can be deleted*** adjectivally in this way (as you might say *Programs are now **fully tested***, for example). Standard phrasing would be *[This / these / your / etc.] programs **can now** be deleted*. Note that for a cut-down style "status message" it would be perfectly normal not to start with a determiner (i.e. - "newspaper headlinese" style), but it's not normal to do this in ordinary conversational contexts.

Comment: Originally, it was meant to be an entry in change log: Defines are now can be set using configuration window. I've tried to replace it with something less specific in my question.

Comment: Well, I have a programming background, so I know what *Defines are now can be set using configuration window* is supposed to mean. English it ain't, but it would be quite difficult to convey the full meaning in syntactically valid English without using a *lot* more words.

Comment: I believe i could have used *Defines are now configurable using "configuration window"* or something like that and spared myself lots of time researching this issue %)

Comment: I used to call them *hard-coded parameters,* for the benefit of non-coders. But just *Enhanced configurability* would do for a "change log", unless you want to specify what new adjustments are now possible (in which case you may as well say *why* users might want to change the previously hard-coded default).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is a change log for a component made for reuse by other programmers, they are aware what defines are and why would they want to change them. Apart from "are now can be" sentence does its job perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No and no. The three acceptable versions of these sentences are as follows:

> The programs now can be run.
>
> The programs now can be deleted.
>
> The programs are now able to be run/deleted.

The use of "are" is neither needed nor grammatical unless connected with another word; in the last example, for instance, "are able" followed by the infinitive "to be."

You can say,

> The programs are elegant/well designed/functioning properly,

but not,

> *The programs are can be [anything].

Comment: The thing is i do not know where did i pick up this form, but it is googleable, for example: http://www.sunywcc.edu/cms/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/FAQs_for_College_Website.pdf (rather large pdf be careful) contains it (search for "can now be", second occurance). I do understand what is wrong with that, but i don't understand why such usage can be easily encountered( i can provide dozens of links)

Comment: Yes, but not "*are* can now be." As  you correctly pointed out, the problem is with the use of "are," not "can now be," right?

Comment: In the pdf i've linked there is a sentence:
`Non high school graduates who meet the required ‘Ability to Benefit’ placement test scores and are admitted
into the College’s 24-credit GED program are now can be considered matriculated and are eligible to apply for
federal and state financial aid. ` 
As you can see it is basicaly the same construction i've used in my question:
"... Graduates ... *are now can be* considered ..."

Please, don't think i'm just being bitter because i'm wrong, i just want to understand the issue better.

Comment: @Goldseeker The example you cite looks like a pure error—the writer started out to say one thing (either *are* or *now can be*) then decided on the other, but rather than properly replacing the old construction just accidentally added the new one. It may also be that this kind of construction (are + present tense verb that doesn't need it) is attractive to some non-native speakers. There is a famous example, *All your base **are belong** to us*, which became an internet sensation partly because it sounds so wrong to native English speakers (but apparently made sense to the translator).

Comment: @1006a, sorry, but i don't believe it is nowhere near **all your base are belong to us** meme. The example I cited is written by a native speaker. It seems that "can be" is used not as a verb, but as a helper(for the lack of a better word) to form an adjective from a verb. For now i can not find more trustworthy sources of such usage, but it seems that this error is spread even among native speakers.
For that matter **is now can be** gets a LOT of hits in google

Comment: @1006a Several first hits(at least for me google search is personalized to some degree) are announcements like "[ProductName] is now can be purchased".  Yet i do struggle to find any usages in trustworthy sources apart from pdf i've linked which is a FAQ from some Community College in USA.

Comment: @Goldseeker To my ear (native speaker of American English), it is the same—equally wrong, and a construction that no native speaker would use. Other examples would be "they are need to X" or "you are look good." In both cases, the *are* is wrong. The correct forms, respectively, would be "they need to X" and either "you look good" or "you are look*ing* good." One other possibility: I googled "is now can be" and several of the first examples should be parsed like [where X *is now*] [*can be*...] or [where X *is*] [*now can be*] rather than [X] [*is now can be*].

Comment: @Mark i've accepted your answer, as i am conviced you're right,but any comments about why this error is so widespread would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Goldseeker: The error is certainly ***not*** "widespread"! Apart from this very page, there are no instances at all on Google for "are now can be deleted", and 3 of the 4 instances of "are now can be run" are on this page as well. The other one is, as 1006a points out, a very careless lapse which the writer would be mortified to have called to his attention. You need to be more careful in evaluating "prevalence" for unfamiliar usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm talking about **are/is now can be" the specific verb after that is not important and there are a lot hits apart from this page, some of them from native speakers, but most of them of chineese and russian origin

Comment: @Goldseeker: If by "widespread error" you mean this is an error that Chinese and Russian speakers are particularly likely to make then maybe you have a point (though it's obviously nothing like the ***really*** widespread tendency for Russians to omit articles in English, for example). I'm saying it's not an error that *native speakers* are likely to make. Because of that, it's ***very*** noticeable - which makes me doubt that it really does occur very often even among nns, since I for one haven't noticed any such tendency here on ELL.

Comment: @MarkHubbard, Why "The programs now can be run"? Shouldn't be "The programs now can be ran"?